# Does maxHttpHeaderSize on Apache Tomcat consider all headers or is this a config "specific to a single header"?

Tags: java, http, tomcat, http-headers

I'm looking at Apache Tomcat docs: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html and I'm not sure if the 'maxHttpHeaderSize' set a maximum size based on the sum of ALL headers size or is this a configuration for a single header size.

[image]

Does maxHttpHeaderSize on Apache Tomcat consider all headers or is this a config "for a specific header size"?